# EC_KEY verification failed

Tags: c, openssl, valgrind

Im creating a program where i generate an EC_KEY pair and then i try to create an other EC_KEY with the public key of the previous one.

this is the header file `hblk_crypto.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <stdint.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>

# define EC_CURVE   NID_secp256k1
# define EC_PUB_LEN 65

uint8_t *sha256(int8_t const *s, size_t len, uint8_t digest[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH]);

EC_KEY *ec_create(void);

uint8_t *ec_to_pub(EC_KEY const *key, uint8_t pub[EC_PUB_LEN]);

EC_KEY *ec_from_pub(uint8_t const pub[EC_PUB_LEN]);
```

`EC_KEY *ec_create(void);` the function used to create a key

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "hblk_crypto.h"

EC_KEY *ec_create()
{
  EC_KEY *key = EC_KEY_new();
  EC_GROUP *group;
  if(key == NULL)
    return NULL;
  group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(EC_CURVE);
  if(group == NULL)
    return NULL;
  EC_KEY_set_group(key, group);
  EC_KEY_generate_key(key);
  EC_GROUP_free(group);
  return key;
}
```

My Function  `ec_from_pub(uint8_t const pub[EC_PUB_LEN]);` generates a key from a public key

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "hblk_crypto.h"

EC_KEY *ec_from_pub(uint8_t const pub[EC_PUB_LEN]){

  EC_KEY *key = NULL;
  EC_POINT *pubKey = NULL;
  const EC_GROUP *group = NULL;
  BN_CTX *ctx;
  char *buf;
  int i;

  buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*(EC_PUB_LEN + 1));

  for(i=0;i<EC_PUB_LEN;i++){
    buf[i] = (char) pub[i];
  }

  key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(EC_CURVE);

  if(key == NULL)
    return NULL;

  group = EC_KEY_get0_group(key);

  if(group == NULL){
    EC_KEY_free(key);
    return NULL;
  }

  pubKey = EC_POINT_new(group);
  ctx = BN_CTX_new();
  EC_POINT_hex2point(group, buf, pubKey, ctx);

  if(pubKey == NULL){
    EC_KEY_free(key);
    BN_CTX_free(ctx);
    return NULL;
  }

  EC_KEY_set_public_key(key, pubKey);
  EC_POINT_free(pubKey);
  BN_CTX_free(ctx);
  free(buf);
  return key;
}
```

The  Method `uint8_t *ec_to_pub(EC_KEY const *key, uint8_t pub[EC_PUB_LEN]);` convert the ec key to an array of `uint8_t`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "hblk_crypto.h"


uint8_t *ec_to_pub(EC_KEY const *key, uint8_t pub[EC_PUB_LEN]){
  const EC_POINT *publicKey;
  EC_GROUP *group;
  BN_CTX *ctx;
  point_conversion_form_t form;
  char *pKey;
  int i;

  if(key == NULL)
    return NULL;
  publicKey = EC_KEY_get0_public_key(key);
  if(publicKey == NULL)
    return NULL;
  group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(EC_CURVE);
  if(group == NULL){
    return NULL;
  }
  form = POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED;
  ctx = BN_CTX_new();
  pKey = EC_POINT_point2hex(group,publicKey,form,ctx);
  if(pKey == NULL){
    EC_GROUP_free(group);
    BN_CTX_free(ctx);
    return NULL;
  }
  for(i=0;i<EC_PUB_LEN;i++){
    pub[i] = (uint8_t)pKey[i];
  }

  EC_GROUP_free(group);
  BN_CTX_free(ctx);
  free(pKey);

  return pub;
}
```

the statement `EC_KEY_check_key(key2)` return null.
this is the main.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "hblk_crypto.h"

void _print_hex_buffer(uint8_t const *buf, size_t len);

int main(void)
{
  EC_KEY *key, *key2;
  uint8_t pub[EC_PUB_LEN], pub2[EC_PUB_LEN];

  /* Prerequisites */
  key = ec_create();
  if (!key)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "ec_create() failed\n");
      return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  printf("Successfully created EC key pair\n");

  if (!ec_to_pub(key, pub))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "ec_to_pub() failed\n");
      EC_KEY_free(key);
      return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  printf("Public key: ");
  _print_hex_buffer(pub, EC_PUB_LEN);
  printf("\n");

  /* Test `ec_from_pub()` */
  key2 = ec_from_pub(pub);
  if (!key2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "ec_from_pub() failed\n");
      EC_KEY_free(key);
      return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  if (!EC_KEY_check_key(key2))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Key2 verification failed\n");
      return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  printf("Successfully created EC key from public key\n");

  /* Extract public key from new key */
  if (!ec_to_pub(key2, pub2))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "ec_to_pub() failed\n");
      EC_KEY_free(key);
      EC_KEY_free(key2);
      return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  printf("Public key: ");
  _print_hex_buffer(pub2, EC_PUB_LEN);
  printf("\n");

  /* Cleanup */
  EC_KEY_free(key);
  EC_KEY_free(key2);

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

and when i run valgrind ./ec_from_pub-main-test i get the followin output.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/holbertonschool-zero_day/crypto$ valgrind --track-origins=yes ./ec_from_pub-test
==3688== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3688== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3688== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3688== Command: ./ec_from_pub-test
==3688==
Successfully created EC key pair
Public key: 3034383830393442454635453132433639443935353130433146353542333845384146454142353943423333373438433830313230364545364331353531453742
==3688== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3688==    at 0x4F21BA5: ossl_ctype_check (in /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==3688==    by 0x4EFE122: BN_hex2bn (in /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==3688==    by 0x4F587A0: EC_POINT_hex2point (in /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==3688==    by 0x401133: ec_from_pub (in /home/vagrant/holbertonschool-zero_day/crypto/ec_from_pub-test)
==3688==    by 0x400EA0: main (in /home/vagrant/holbertonschool-zero_day/crypto/ec_from_pub-test)
==3688==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==3688==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3688==    by 0x401080: ec_from_pub (in /home/vagrant/holbertonschool-zero_day/crypto/ec_from_pub-test)
==3688==    by 0x400EA0: main (in /home/vagrant/holbertonschool-zero_day/crypto/ec_from_pub-test)
==3688==
==3688== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==3688==    at 0x4F21BB1: ossl_ctype_check (in /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==3688==    by 0x4EFE122: BN_hex2bn (in /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==3688==    by 0x4F587A0: EC_POINT_hex2point (in /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==3688==    by 0x401133: ec_from_pub (in /home/vagrant/holbertonschool-zero_day/crypto/ec_from_pub-test)
==3688==    by 0x400EA0: main (in /home/vagrant/holbertonschool-zero_day/crypto/ec_from_pub-test)
==3688==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==3688==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3688==    by 0x401080: ec_from_pub (in /home/vagrant/holbertonschool-zero_day/crypto/ec_from_pub-test)
==3688==    by 0x400EA0: main (in /home/vagrant/holbertonschool-zero_day/crypto/ec_from_pub-test)
==3688==
Key2 verification failed
==3688==
==3688== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3688==     in use at exit: 2,688 bytes in 68 blocks
==3688==   total heap usage: 2,963 allocs, 2,895 frees, 114,115 bytes allocated
==3688==
==3688== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3688==    definitely lost: 160 bytes in 2 blocks
==3688==    indirectly lost: 2,528 bytes in 66 blocks
==3688==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3688==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3688==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3688== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3688==
==3688== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3688== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Q: What happens if you *DON'T* run your program through Valgrind?  Do you still get "key2 verification failed"?   Q: Have you stepped through ec_to_pub() in your debugger to find out *WHY* verification is failing?  Q: "key2 verification failed" is the main question you're asking about, correct?  PS: `malloc(sizeof(char)*(EC_PUB_LEN + 1))` is silly, isn't it?  Why not just `malloc(EC_PUB_LEN + 1)`?

Comment: i still get key2 verification failed if i dont run using valgrind. and yes im asking why m having key verfication failed. `malloc(EC_PUB_LEN + 1)` already tried it the same problem occurs

Comment: This code isn't complete.  Please update your question with a [mcve] so that others can run your program and see the same results you do.

Comment: Also, you should compile with -g so that valgrind will report line numbers.

Comment: Well i this is the code im using and i tried compiling using -g i guess its output is not very helpful

Comment: You are trying to put a secp256k1 uncompressed point (publickey) as hex in a 65-byte buffer; that is wrong. The _octetstring_ format of such a point is 65 _bytes_, but the hex format is 131 _characters_ (65 times 2, plus a null terminator). Also the pointer returned from `EC_POINT_point2hex` is allocated by `OPENSSL_malloc` and should be freed by `OPENSSL_free` not plain `free`. `EC_KEY_check_key` returns type `int` with 1 for true and 0 for false (effectively boolean, but C before C99 doesn't have boolean), but cannot be null, because only characters and pointers can be null.

Comment: So how can i assign a public key to `uint8_t pub[EC_PUB_LEN]` knowing that i should use `EC_PUB_LEN`